# UK - What type of spider is this?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

Location: East Anglia, UK.

Approximate size (including legs at full span; like in the image): about 3cm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be a Noble False Widow *Steatoda nobilis*

[image]

From http://britishspiders.org.uk/wiki2015/index.php?title=File:Steatoda_nobilis.jpg

It apparently is thought to be introduced to the UK, and there are some reports that the bite has caused some issues for some people.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steatoda_nobilis

Comment: I had suspected as much but I wanted to see if someone else would come to the same conclusion. In fact the spider in the image you have provided is pretty much a carbon copy of the one I have shown (although mine had a smaller abdomen). I have caught ~5 of these spiders this year so far; all of which have reasonably small abdomens compared to what I would expect on a false widow; I'm assuming that makes them males? I have caught one with a very large abdomen which was unmistakeably a False Widow Spider, but that was 2 years ago.